# Reinstalling broken xterm (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, xterm

So, my problem is that after a series of problems (which I'll describe bellow) I have a damage xterm package, which now always shows an error when installing new packages, updating, etc.

It all started with me running out of space on root, dpkg damaging, followed by GUI not being able to boot. I fixed it with via root shell via GRUB by freeing some space. Now I can log into system and use it just fine, except when I want to install some package I get this error at the end:

```
dpkg: error processing package xterm (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xterm
(sometimes followed by this) E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried installing, reinstalling and removing it, but it always says that the package is damaged, you can't do this or that as long as it's damaged.

So how do I fix this? As far as I know I don't need xterm, so if the safest solution would be to kill it, then I won't miss, just tell me how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please always include the complete command outputs in your question. The small extracts you provided don't give enough information to see what exactly is going on. What exactly does it say when you `sudo apt install --reinstall xterm`?

Comment: @ByteCommander, actually I haven't tried the  `--reinstall` option, because I'm somewhat new to solving this kind of issues, I didn't know about it and just tried other stuff I seen on different problem discussions. This actually seems to have worked, so thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, according to the comment reply, all that needed to be run was

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xterm
```